# When I enter command npm start it generates ENOENT error

Tags: reactjs, enoent

I am new to ReactJs and firstly entered npx create-react-app my-app and after its installation, I entered npm start command. It says

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Anonymous\OneDrive\Projects\react/package.json

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Anonymous\OneDrive\Projects\react\package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRHx1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should run the command in `my-app` folder, where you probably have a `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the directory where `package.json` exist in your project which has been created by `create-react-app`. Then try to run `npm start`

if you are in same directory, then try to run `npm cache clean`, and after this `npm start`.